# After recording audio and save to document directory unable to play audio file with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm working on application which has record audio and play that recorded file which is store in document directory.

**Here is my code:**

Record button method.

```
(IBAction)stopButtonPressed:(id)sender{

     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

     if (button.selected) { // Play recorded file.

     self.stopButton.selected = NO;

     NSError *error;

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url     error:&error];

    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;

    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.audioPlayer play];

    }

    else{ // Stop recording.

    self.stopButton.selected = YES;

    if (recordTimer) {

    [recordTimer invalidate];

    }

    [self.audioPlayer stop];

    self.recordButton.selected = NO;

    [audioRecorder stop];

    self.readyLabel.text = @"READY";

    [self insertNewRecording];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm able to record the file but unable to play that recorded file.

Comment: have you checked you error?

Comment: It not showing me any error.

Comment: and your NSError *error is always null after self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

um..I am not sure. But as a test, maybe you can try if you can play the file by specifying its name? E.g. you got a forest.mp3 to play and the key part of the code can be like this:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"forest" ofType:@"mp3"]; 
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
NSError *audioError = nil; 
av = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData  error:&audioError];
```

If everything went well, maybe it's something to do with audioRecorder.url in your code?

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: yes it was related to path issue. now I'm able to play the recorded file.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're using ARC, in which case you'll need to retain the AVAudioPlayer as it sets to nil automatically. In your header file enter the following`

> @property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

Hope this works for you,
Cheers Jim